# Could not load type MyNameSpace.PageName

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have switched to a new PC and got the latest version out of source safe but now when I do a ReBuild I get Could not load type then the name of my namespace.the name of my pages?

It seems ok if I do a Build.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** Once a Rebuild is done it removes the Namespace.dll and then doing a Build it fails with the same errors.

**UPDATE 2:** I think it has something to do with aspnet_compiler.exe? Do standard Web Applications run this after a build? I have setup another test Web Application and it runs Csc.exe but not aspnet_compiler.exe but I can't see anywhere in my project where its configured to run this.

Comment: Is there a version difference between your previous PC and the version in your source control repository?

Comment: don't think so. i checked the files in from my old pc and then did get latest on new pc.  the OS is different though!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have refferenced a DLL directly, instead of a project in a solution.

This could cause a rebuild to work

Answer (score 0):

I've lost references before when I've moved to a new machine.  So, I would start by checking the references on the projects with the errors.

Comment: Have you installed all of the VS service packs on the new machine?

Comment: As far as I am aware. I am running Version 9.0.30729.1 SP

Comment: My next step would be to delete the solution (not the projects; just the solution) and manually create a new one.  Then verify that project references are all still working and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I found in my csproj file the following:

```
<AspNetCompiler PhysicalPath="C:\Projects\MyProject" Debug="false" VirtualPath="/MyProject" />
```

Not sure what this is doing, I think it was put in there for some reason.